# How to call this stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

PL/SQL to call:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETQUOTE(
i_SALES_TYPE IN HR.sales_type,
o_DESCRITPION_TYPE OUT HR.description_type
)
```

TYPE sales_type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "sales_type"
```

TYPE description_type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE description_type AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000)
```

Comment: Your definition of the "sales_type" type appears to be incomplete, can you post the full definition.  Also, the "sales_type" DDL is creating a case-sensitive identifier that the procedure definition is not using.  The type definition should match the procedure definition.

Comment: Hi Justin, sales_type is complete, i just checked again, yes it looks something missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, with a few assumptions (e.g. that the o_DESCRIPTION_TYPE parameter can be NULL on input) your calling code should look something like this

```
DECLARE
    in_param  sales_type;
    out_param description_type;
BEGIN
    -- First set up in_param
    in_param := sales_type.someConstructor();
    -- Now make call
    getquote( in_param, out_param );
    -- out_param should now be populated
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks alot Sodved, can i also know how if i want to initialize the value of sales_type to a string 'abc'?

Comment: Sorry, I would need to know the structure of sales_type to help there. It is missing from your original question, as pointed out by @Justin Cave

Comment: Hi Sodved, when i clicked on the type, it just showed up as "CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "sales_type" ", could there be something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I do all my coding from the command line so have no idea what's meant to happen when you "click" on something. If the object is owned by the HR schema, try connecting as that user and you may get more information.